# Why do I need to reference a dll which I'm not using directly?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reference

I have source code I received from an external developer, this code is divided up into 4 types of projects: Their framework, the environment for my project (lets call it "ENV"),  the application base (call it "Base") and the application itself (about 20 dlls I'll collectively call "App").

Now, I've added another layer to this mess, a dll by the name AdvanceFeatures. It lays right under the ENV (on top of the framework).
This dll references nothing but the framework, and the ENV references it.
Only the ENV makes use of this AdvanceFeatures dll, while Base and App use the only the ENV.

The way I'm working here is most objects in the App are defined in Base and inherit/implement classes/interfaces in ENV. Also a small part of those objects (in App and Base) inherit/implement classes/interfaces from the framework itself (but this is quite rare).

So far all is well, apart from one fact. The compiler demands I'll add a reference to the AdvanceFeatures dll from each one of the dlls in App, and from Base.

I don't make any use of AdvanceFeatures outside of ENV, so why is these references needed?

Edit: I've created a demo project for this problem. This is the project details:

```
Assembly: AdvanceFeatures
References: Nothing (Reference project-folder is empty)
Classes: Decorator, IEnvClass, IDecorator
IDecorator contents:
namespace AdvanceFeatures
{
    public interface IDecorator
    {
        IEnvClass Decorated { get; }
        void Decorate();
    }
}

IEnvClass contents: 
namespace AdvanceFeatures
{
    public interface IEnvClass
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

Decorator contents:
namespace AdvanceFeatures
{
    public class Decorator : IDecorator
    {

        public Decorator(IEnvClass decorated)
        {
            Decorated = decorated;
        }

        #region Implementation of IDecorator

        public IEnvClass Decorated { get; set; }

        public void Decorate()
        {
            Decorated.Name = "NewName";
        }   

        #endregion
    }
}

Assembly: ENV
References: AdvanceFeatures (Compiled DLL)
Contents of only class SomeEnvClass:

namespace ENV
{
    public class SomeEnvClass : AdvanceFeatures.IEnvClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        private readonly AdvanceFeatures.IDecorator _decorator;

        public SomeEnvClass(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            _decorator = new AdvanceFeatures.Decorator(this);
            _decorator.Decorate();
        }

        public string Foo()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}


Assembly: TestBase
References: ENV (compiled DLL)
Contents of only class SomeEnvExtendingClass:

namespace TestBase
{
    public class SomeEnvExtandingClass : ENV.SomeEnvClass
    {
        public SomeEnvExtandingClass(string name) : base(name)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Error 1   The type 'AdvanceFeatures.IEnvClass' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'AdvanceFeatures, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.   E:\Projects\Dev\TestReferenceInheritance\TestBase\SomeEnvExtandingClass.cs  3   18  TestBase

Now, I know why the DLL must be made available to the compiled executable, but why should the developer know the inner workings of ENV (more specifically, it's inheritance tree) in order to extend it?

Comment: Do any of the types in ENV derive types in AdvanceFeatures?

Comment: Yes. Why would that matter? (My probelem is that I don't see why the implementation of ENV should require references in APP or Base)

Comment: Because if you have a type P in assembly A, and type Q extending P in assembly B, then you can't use Q from B without also referencing A, because the type is *incomplete* without the definition of the base type.  Giving *specific* compiler output would help us determine what exactly is causing it to demand a reference.

Comment: That's not right. Users of Q Don't need to know anything about Q's implementation, nor do they need to know about it's inheritance tree (it's encapsulation 101). If they don't need to know who Q inherits from, why do they need to reference the base assembly?

Comment: inheritance has _nothing_ to do with encapsulation on the contrary (in C# at least e.g. c++ can be different). Inheritance is public so there's no encapsulation. And the knowledge is indeed required by the compiler. How would the compiler know what to do with anything in Q that depends on Q extending P if it doesn't know P?

Comment: Think about it for a moment, if Q and P are already compiled, why would the compiler need to know or do anything with both of them? they're already compiled. The third dll is the one causing me problems.

Comment: P.S, I didn't say inheritance is encapsulation, I said that encapsulation means I don't know (nor do I need to know) the inner working of a class in order to use it (this includes both non public\internal class items and it's inheritance tree)

Comment: @Neowizard sure you don't need to know but the compiler does and a DLL is not compiled (completely) it's in IL and needs further compilation to be part of a program. There's no information in B in regards to P so the compiler need information of P

Comment: @Neowizard: Have you actually tried tried this scenario, or are you just assuming things?  I've experienced this scenario first-hand.

Comment: @Rune FS, I think You're confusing the .Net compiler and the runtime. The code is completely compiled buy the compiler, but the JIT compiler is another matter all together. Am I not getting you right?

Comment: @cdhowie, I've tried this a couple of times, and again just now. The compiler wants me to add the reference. I'm not questioning the compiler requirements, I'm asking *why* do I need to reference a dll which I'm not directly using.

Comment: @neowizard. No confusion on my part. The answer is still the same you need to reference it because you are using it. Whether it's indirectly, directly doesn't matter. Let's say you didn't have to you then compile with no errors but your program doesn't work because the dll that holds the code you use indirectly is nowhere to be found. Wouldn't you expect that if your code compiles it can at least execute?

Comment: @Neowizard: For example, the members on the type you derive from are not contained in the assembly of the deriving type.  So the compiler can't know what other members on the deriving type exists without also being told about the reference to the assembly containing the type you derive from.

Answer (score 10):

I read all the answers and comments so I came up with this example. Maybe it is a bit easier to understand. :)

Interfaces.dll

```
public interface DoesntAcceptValidAndAccurateAnswersOrComments {
    bool ImAlwaysRight();
}
```

Classes.dll - References Interfaces.dll

```
public class Neowizard : Interfaces.DoesntAcceptValidAndAccurateAnswersOrComments {
    public bool ImAlwaysRight() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Program.exe - References Classes.dll

```
public class StackOverflowDotCom {
    public static void Main() {
        Neowizard someGuy = new Neowizard(); // CS0012
        someGuy.ImAlwaysRight();
    }
}
```

This has everything to do with the compiler. When it tries to compile Program.exe, it sees an object of type Neowizard. What it also sees is that it implements some interface called DoesntAcceptValidAndAccurateAnswersOrComments, but without a reference to Interfaces.dll it cannot find it, thus it cannot compile because it is an interface that as far as the compiler is concerned, does not exist to Program.exe.

Because Program.exe uses Neowizard, it must also use anything Neowizard derives from, which happens to be the interface. This does not just apply to interfaces, and has zero to do with encapsulation. This a rule of the C# Programming Language that is enforced by the compiler.

If you want to argue the case more, then you should go ask someone on the C# Compiler Team more about it, but please quit dogging on everyone's answer who has tried to help you with your question when their answers are actually quite accurate and well educated.

Comment: Apart from being overly snide and quite quick to judge, I think you're right, that this question would be best directed to the C# language definition or it's compiler team.

Comment: A little heart poke, but a little snide, I agree. If you go to Channel9 (Msdn) and watch some of their C# videos from the C# team, they explain things about the C# compiler like this in detail. I think the name of the show is Behind the Code, and there's one other I do not remember the name of. But the people you want to hear it from are people like Eric Lipert, (Jon Skeet works for Google, but also is very well spoken and educated), and a few others.

Comment: Great answer!

I actually just faced this issue after never really having to think about this in the past. I guess the main reason would be the fact that referenced DLLs do not compile into parent DLLs as this would hurt DLL re-use (eg. an utility dll used by dozen other dlls).

Answer (score 4):

If you in one assembly have

```
public class Bar{
...
}
```

and in another have

```
public class Foo{
   public Bar MyBar{get;set;}
}
```

and in a third have

```
public class FooBar{
    public Foo {get;set;}
}
```

then you could write:

```
Bar myBar = new FooBar().Foo.MyBar;
```

if you haven't told the compiler about the definition of bar how would it be able to compile the last line of code?

or to answer your question more directly. When using an assembly that references another assembly, there's the possibility that your code might be using stuff from that other assembly directly E.g. if a return type is declared in the other assembly or indirectly when objects of types defined in the other assembly is used in the implementation of methods or as private fields in the assembly you are referencing directly. The compiler need to know about these types to do it's work. It relies on you to tell it where it can find the information of those types. I.e. add the reference

**EDIT**

To clarify a bit there's no rule requiring you to reference the same dll as the dll you are using is using. You have to reference a dll that says it's the same. That's why you can sign a dll. Then you are gauranteed it's always the same implementation (or at least made by some one with access to the key)

the possibility of using a different assembly however enforces are requirement on the dll/program using the dll in the middle. You need to explicitly declare which implementation of a given assembly you wish to use.

Comment: Like I wrote in the comment on Tusken360 reply, no changes where made in App and Base when AdvanceFeatures was added, so there's no way I'm calling anything in AdvanceFeatures directly from App or Base.

Comment: @Neowizard and as I wrote it doesn't matter whether you call it direct or inderectly. It actually doesn't even matter whether you use it or not. If there's the possibility that you might. Ie the assembly you reference references another assembly, then you need to reference both

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. What you're saying doesn't make sense. why would the user of my DLL (in this case, me in APP) need to know what is referenced in my DLL (ENV)?

Comment: @neowizard if it doesn't make sense then answer this: if program reference you're dll and nothing more (you dll does not include the dllsit reference) how would the program know what to do with all the types from the dll you reference. It wouldn't have the binaries. Just because you reference one dll doesn't mean that all the dll's referenced by that dll is automatically included

Comment: if my program is referencing a dll, and that dll is referencing another, why would my program need to know anything about the other dll? my program's not using it directly, so it's not it's business. The first dll is responsible for being able to work with the other, not my program.

Comment: @Neowizard the dll in the middle gives every one using it a contract they need to fulfill to be able to use that dll. Part of that contract is supplying the DLLs the assembly in the middle needs. Whether you like it or not that's the design and the flexibility described above is part of that design. This makes it possible to use a new version of the bottom dll with out recompiling the dll in the middle

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially two possibilities:

1. You might use part of the AdvanceFeatures library without realising it, for example at some point getting a reference to a class which inherits from a class in AdvanceFeatures.  This class might be tiny, you might have an enum in AdvanceFeatures which gets returned by a method in ENV for example.
2. You haven't done anything like this and it's just the fact that the library still needs to be there.  Unless you embed the AdvanceFeature dll inside ENV you won't actually be able to use ENV without AdvanceFeature being around somewhere.  Usually that just means it needs to be in the same folder as your executable.  It may be worth checking you have the libraries set to copy local etc. in their properties, or the references to their properties.

Comment: Regarding 1, It cant be. AdvanceFeatures is using a decorator pattern, and so I don't return any value from any of it's non-internal methods, and I've made no changes to the code in App or Base (so I'm not referencing any of AdvanceFeatures classes).

Comment: Regarding 2, I don't have a problem with using the dll (placing it in the same folder etc...), the problem is that the VS\compiler wants me to reference it from APP and Base

Comment: You wouldn't necissarily need to make any changes to the code in app or base in order to reference one of the classes in AdvanceFeatures (e.g. var MyItem = ENV.foo.bar();) since the var is implicitly whatever is returned by bar, you wouldn't need to change this code if bar changed to return a different type (provided it still had any methods etc. that were used).  This still might not be the problem in your case.