# Why is an unused assembly referenced required here

Tags: c#, reference

I have an exe referencing a dll.

In the dll there's some methods, the two we're interested in are:

```
private static CacheItemPolicy _policy = new CacheItemPolicy();

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static void SetValue(string Key, object Value)
{
    SetValue(Key, Value, _policy);
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static void SetValue(string Key, object Value, TimeSpan TTL)
{
    SetValue(Key, Value, GetPolicy(TTL));
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
private static CacheItemPolicy GetPolicy(TimeSpan TTL)
{
    return new CacheItemPolicy()
    {
        SlidingExpiration = TTL
    };
}
```

In my exe when I try to call this method: using just `cache.SetValue(key, item);` it compiles and works fine, but when called using `cache.SetValue(key, item, new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));`  I get the following exception:

> Error  1   The type 'System.Runtime.Caching.CacheItemPolicy' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Why does the compiler say that I need to add this reference to an assembly that I'm not directly using in my code at this point?

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing. I looked at [Why do I need to reference a dll which I'm not using directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254837/why-do-i-need-to-reference-a-dll-which-im-not-using-directly) but it refers to interfaces and that is not the case here.

Edit: there is also this:

```
protected static void SetValue(string Key, object Value, CacheItemPolicy Policy)
{
    // work is done here
}
```

But that's protected and shouldn't be visible to the calling exe.

Edit2: when this above `SetValue` that takes a `CacheItemPolicy` is set to `private` or `internal`, it works, why does `protected` (and `protected internal`) cause it to require the assembly?

Comment: Is there an overload not shown that takes/returns CacheItemPolicy? I'm wondering if this is simply an issue of overload resolution..

Comment: Hi Seph, if you are referring to my comment, it's because protected is visible to derived classes.  Private means its limited to that specific class, and internal means its limited to the same assembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since that static `SetValue` is protected, it's visible to derived classes.

So, if you can derive from the class (i.e. it's public), then there's a chance you could derive and use that method, meaning the reference is required.

Comment: Can you elaborate why then is the reference not required when calling SetValue with only 2 parameters despite no other change in the code?

Comment: As far as I can see it doesn't matter how/why you call it.  The parts of the class that are visible to other assemblies include the use of the type CacheItemPolicy, because the class isn't `sealed` and is `public` (presumably), it's inviting the user of the class to derive from it.  If they did that, then they would be able to call the `SetValue` that takes a `CacheItemPolicy`.  Does that help?

Comment: Solutions: make the class `sealed` if you don't want people to derive from it / make the `SetValue` overload with `CacheItemPolicy` private or internal (maybe protected internal if you derive from that class in the same referenced assembly).

Comment: On *that* point, maybe because you're calling an overload with 3 parameters, and it doesn't know what `CacheItemPolicy` *is*, it needs to have the assembly that defines it loaded so it can see if your call that passes a `TimeSpan` is intended to call the `TimeSpan`-based overload or the `CacheItemPolicy` one.  (It wants to establish is if there's an implicit conversion available from `TimeSpan` to `CacheItemPolicy`, for example)

Comment: One way to test that: you could add a dummy parameter to either the `TimeSpan` or `CacheItemPolicy` version of `SetValue`, so they don't have the same number of parameters.

Comment: "It wants to establish is if there's an implicit conversion available from `TimeSpan` to `CacheItemPolicy`" that makes sense now.