# Assembly reference error on not used (and referenced) assembly, why do I this error?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, .net-assembly

In my solution I have three projects (Web, Business and Data) all are targeting .net 4.5.1.
Web references Business and Business references Data.

I need to execute a intitialization method in those three projects depending on the application start. So I have created a Boot class in all projects.

The Boot class in Business inherit from Boot class in Data and Boot class in Web inherite from Boot class in Business

So I have this code :

In Data project :

```
namespace Data
{
    public class Boot
    {
        public Boot() 
        {
            // init execution
        }
    }
}
```

In Business project :

```
namespace Business
{
    public class Boot : Data.Boot
    {
        public Boot() : base()
        {
            // init execution
        }
    }
}
```

In Web project :

```
namespace Web
{
    public class Boot : Business.Boot
    {
        public Boot() : base()
        {
            // init execution
        }
    }
}
```

And when I compile I have an error on my Boot class in Web project :

> The type 'Data.Boot' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

And I don't understand why my Web project needs to references my Data project.. It never use Data.Boot directly..

Comment: If `Data Project's` output is `dll` then add that dll in references of `Business Project`.

Comment: My Business project already references the Data.dll and my Web project references the Business.dll

Comment: can you show `namespaces` appearing for each class.

Comment: Also please clarify that all projects are built using same version of .Net Framework?

Comment: @HassanNisar I update the explaination, all project are targeting .net 4.5.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I need to reference a dll which I'm not using directly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254837/why-do-i-need-to-reference-a-dll-which-im-not-using-directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a reference to your data project from within your web and business project. In your case, your web layer is dependent on the business layer **and** data layer.

To summarize:

- Web project references business project and data project
- business references data project

Comment: Ok, and if I don't want that my Web project know my Data project I need to use another system to synchronise initializations ?

Comment: If you web project is dependent on functionality in your data layer, it must know it. Why would you want your web project not to know about the data layer?

Comment: To replace by another data layer without change anything in my Web project. While I write that I realise I have a dependency with Data not directly but through Business.. I manage to find another method to cascading call my initialization.

Comment: In that case you should consider using interfaces.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I want to avoid using interfaces for this case :). I just use another behavior :). Thank for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if Data DLL was referenced in Business project, if yes you have to clean the solution and rebuild it