# How to avoid referencing assembly that only contain base class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have class structure as below:

AssemblyA.dll

```
public abstract class MyBase
```

AssemblyB.dll (references AssemblyA.dll)

```
public sealed class MyClass : MyBase
```

AssemblyC.dll (references AssemblyB.dll)

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.Xyz = "some text";
```

While compiling AssemblyC, compiler raises an error:

> The type 'MyBase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'AssemblyA,.......'.

I understand why the error is and that adding reference of AssemblyA.dll in AssemblyC.dll will resolve the issue.

But I do not want to add that reference. What alternate design practice I should implement to avoid adding that reference?

**More Info:**

Base class `MyBase` is used in AssemblyA.dll for generic implementation like below:

```
class SomeClassInAssemblyA<T> : ISomeInterface where T : MyBase
```

Multiple concrete implementations are defined in AssemblyB.dll including `MyClass` like below:

```
public sealed class MyClass : MyBase
{
    public string Xyz { get; set; }
}
```

Concrete class `MyClass` is used in AssemblyB.dll as well as AssemblyC.dll.

**Objectives:**

- References should be only one way from A to B to C.
- References should be sequencial, C should only refer B AND B should only refer A.

AssemblyA.dll is being used across multiple projects.
That is why `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` cannot be used.
So, if I make the members `internal` in AssemblyA and implement `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` attribute so those could be only visible to AssemblyB; this will not work.
**I can still modify AssemblyA**, but the change should not be explicitly targeted to specific project.

Other two assemblies (B and C) are only used by one project. So, I can change them in any way.

Comment: "What alternate design practice I should implement to avoid adding that reference?" Don't use any type within the assembly. If you use the type in any way (other than by referencing compile-time constants) the assembly *has* to be referenced. Referring to a type in B with a base type in A means you need to know about assembly A - otherwise the compiler can't know what members it provides. What you haven't explained is *why* you don't want assembly C to know about assembly A.

Comment: My only advice is to make common things common.Separate your concerns, and if you are in a pickle like this its time to refactor. I mean there is no design pattern for your business logic and architecture. If you want to separate things in to different projects, make sure that they have a suitable hierarchy

Comment: If you use an assembly, you have to reference it otherwise the compiler has no way to know what you want it to do. You use a derived type, so you are using the assembly...

Comment: Basically, *What alternate design practice I should implement to avoid adding that reference?* there isn't one. The issue here is your trying to do something that makes no sense. You **have** to reference **all assemblies** needed to instanciate the classes that your using (full stop) It's impossible to provide any more advice because what your trying to achieve is unclear (and is also likely too broad for this format).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to reference a dll which I'm not using directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254837/why-do-i-need-to-reference-a-dll-which-im-not-using-directly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate design practice would be to use composition instead of inheritance:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
    private MyBase myBase = ...;
}
```

If your design really makes it possible for AssemblyC to do anything sensible with `MyClass` without knowing about `MyBase` then it must be possible to instantiate `MyClass` without knowing how to initialize `MyBase`. And thus, `MyClass` should contain this knowledge within itself or with help of DI.

In your question you seem to assume that clients of `MyClass` do not depend in any way on `MyBase` so it must be possible for it to be private and not leak out of `MyClass`.